# How to draw Venn diagram of a set containing another set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How can I draw Venn diagram of these two sets:-
S ={5,6}
T={S,1}.
As T={{5,6},1} 5 and 6 aren't the elements of T. So how can I draw Venn diagram.[image]

I can't think of other way than this but then 5,6 becomes elements of T

Comment: Venn diagrams can only illustrate simple set relationships; your scenario shows that it cannot handle an element that is also a set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Venn diagrams can only illustrate simple set relationships; your scenario shows that it cannot handle an element that is also a set.